# add textview programmatically in android studio but it does not display

Tags: android, textview

I want to add TextView programmatically in location.class but it does not display.

The location.xml does not contain any TextView so I want to create TextView programmatically.

How can I solve the problem?

```
public class location extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("gateway");

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.locationlayout);

    Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
    String ble_num=intent.getStringExtra("num");
    int number=Integer.parseInt(ble_num);


        for (int j=0; j<number; j++){
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setText("123");
            textView.setId(j);
            relativeLayout.addView(textView);
        }



}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.location, container, false);
}
}
```

This is the code of location.class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinearLayout to generate it dinamically, but if you really want RelativeLayout

In your fragment :

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.auftrage);
 final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 textView.setText("Text ");     


 int curTextViewId =  2;//or some id number
 textView.setId(curTextViewId);
 final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId);
 textView.setLayoutParams(params);

 layout.addView(textView, params);
```

Comment: Thanks. I use linearlayout to generate it finally. I find it is easier than using relativelayout.